# If you have a base of some subspace can you fill to the base of other bigger subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two subspaces $S,V$ of $W$. If I have a base of $S$ $\{b_1,b_2,...,b_k\}$ and $dimS<dimV$ can I fill this base to the base of $V$, I know that I can extend this base to a base of $W$, but can I do that for a base of $V$? For example base of V is $\{b_1,b_2,....,b_k,b_k+1,..b_l\}$

Comment: If $S$ is also a subspace of $V$ then yes, otherwise you cannot do this in general.

Comment: yes S is subspace of V

Comment: Then yeah: you can always extend the basis of a subspace to a basis for the whole space; in this case we just regard $V$ as the ambient space that $S$ is a subspace inside of.